# How to show different result in two different pages form same ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

how to show different result in two different pages form same ajax in codeigniter

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#department').on('change',function(){
    var deptID = $(this).val(); console.log(deptID);
    if(deptID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: BASE_URL+'User/listHospital',
            data:'id='+deptID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#hospital').html(html);
                $('#specialisation').html('<option value="">Select hospital</option>');
                     $('#special').html('<option value="">Select hospital</option>');
           }
        }); 
    }
});
```

i will get the value in the id i want to pass the id to two diffent function User/listHospital and User/listDoctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the specific parameter as URL identifier:

```
var type = $('#url').val();

url: BASE_URL+type
data: {id: deptID},
```

Can set type value in hidden field and call it via getElementById:

```
<input type="hidden"  id="url" value="User/listHospital"> # in hospital view
<input type="hidden"  id="url" value="User/listDoctor"> # in Doctor view
```

Comment: add what ??`<input type="hidden"` ??

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare data in "listHospital()" function something like this

```
function listHospital()
{
    $data['one']='<option value="">Your Html one</option>';
    $data['two']='<option value="">Your html two</option>';
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

and in ajax you can get these variables like this

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: BASE_URL+'User/listHospital',
    data:'id='+deptID,
    success:function(html){
        var data=JSON.parse(html);
        $('#specialisation').html(data.one);
        $('#special').html(data.two);
    }
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions.